# Mongoid query for array field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a `category` field of `type` `Array` in Mongoid.

> Ex. category: ["val1","val2","val3"]

Now I want to query this Model with `category: ["val1","val2"] such that it returns me the merge of

> Model.where(category: "val1") and Model.where(category: "val2")

I can do it individually for each element of the array but that will be slow I guess because for every individual element it will search all the documents.

I also tried `Model.all_of({category: "val1"},{category: "val2"}).all` but that is not working.

How should I do this?

Comment: Third read is, hopefully, a more accurate one. Try: Model.select{|m|m.category.include?("val1") || m.category.include?("val2")} (provided the category field is never a nil value).

Comment: the first one was more robust and easy

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In mongoid, there is '$in' operator. So you can do this :

```
Model.where(category: { '$in': ['val1', 'val2'] })
```

Comment: This gives me a syntax error. I had to use:

Model.where(category: { '$in' => ['val1', 'val2'] })

Note the use of '=>' instead of ':'

Comment: @AhmedFathy: Or just say `Model.where(:category.in => ['val1', 'val2'])`. Mongoid adds similar methods to Symbol for the other MongoDB operators: `:f.ne => ...`, `:f.gt => ...`, ...

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Criteria](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#all_in) `all_in` to make it simpler:

```
Model.all_in(category: ['val1','val2'])
```

Answer (score 9):

This worked

```
Model.where(:category.in => ['val1','val2'])
```

From [Mongo Docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-queries/#id1)

Answer (score 2):

Or another variant:

```
Model.in(category: ['val1','val2'])
```