# mongoid .where queries not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a model that belongs_to another:

```
class Permission
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :action
  field :action_id, type: String
```

And a corresponding has_many model:

```
class Action
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :permissions
```

I am seeing that 2 basic ActiveRecord queries are not working:

First, sending the object instead of the object id does not work:

```
action = Action.first
permissions = Permission.where(action: action)
permissions.count # this is always 0
```

However, if I use the id, it works fine:

```
Permission.where(action_id: action.id) # this works fine
```

Second, sending an array of ids does not work, ever:

```
Permission.where(action_id: [action.id]) # always empty
```

Does mongoid not support basic ActiveRecord queries?  If not, for the first problem, I can work around it by always using the object id, but for the second, how do I search by an array of targets?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: user `$in` operator, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19868630/1297435

Answer (score 0):

Look into Ruby on Rails reserved words. There is a possibility that is what is causing the .where to break.

http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words